# Show T being prime element in $ F_{2}(T) $

Tags: prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

Show that $X^4+TX^2+T$ is irreducible in $ F_{2}(T) $

Using Eisenstein with T as a prime element this proof is simple. Can I proof that T is prime any easier than in the folowing:

> **Theorem 1**: K is  PID then
>
> > p is irreducible $\Leftrightarrow$  p is prime element $\Leftrightarrow$ (p) is maximal ideal

Since $ K=F_{2}(T) $ is a field $ K[X] $ is a principal ideal domain (PID).

Assume (T) is not an maximal ideal. Obviously (T) contains all polynomials P with $deg_{T}(P) \geq 1$. So in order to find  (m) $\supsetneq$  (T) with $(m) \neq K[X]$ we have to add an element with  $deg_{T}(P) = 0$ to (T). Let $a \neq 0 \in F_{2}$ be this element. Because a is a unit we have $ 1 \in (T)$ Thats a contradiction to $(m) \neq  K[X]$.

$\Rightarrow$ (T) is an maximal ideal and therefore (Theorem 1) T is prime.

Comment: What is $F_2[T]/(T)$??

Comment: of course $F_{2}[T]/(T) \cong F_{2}$. Since $F_{2}$ is a field (T) is maximal thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the full argument (which you probably imply) should be the following.

By [Gauss' Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29), it is enough to show that the polynomial
$$
f = X^4+TX^2+T
$$
is irreducible in $R[X]$, where $R = F_{2}[T]$.

Now you indeed use [Eisenstein's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion), and show that $T$ is prime in $R$. For this, is it enough to note that a polynomial of degree $1$ over a field is always irreducible.